# How to change width of HTML table on browser by jQuery

Tags: jquery, api

I'm making an exam site, i prepared my html for jQuery and now i want to provide user to change width of table when he take mouse on border of table and drag it. because some answers might be longer than my default places.

What api should i use? i'm guessing i should use drag() api but what else i'm gonna need?

I will be also appriciated if you guys can provide me some examples too :)

Comment: Ah smell of fresh homework? :P :) <right right> by the way **all api** reside here: http://api.jquery.com/ `.css` or `width` might suit you

Comment: _"What api should i use? "_ Did you search the API site?

Comment: @gdoron yes i did. i studied on drag() and drop() api. And i also searched "width" on http://api.jquery.com/ address.

drag & drop are the closest i could found. but it selects whole item. what i want is to selecting particular parts

Comment: @Tats_innit , nope. thay don't teach us jQuery at school and they don't expect us to use it in out homeworks. did you really think every people on planet is coming here and ask before looking into actual source of jQuery? ;)

Comment: @Timur :)) cool bruv, Nopes Bruv. I might be able to help you out if you need any now? B-) cheers BTW - you only want expandable table?

Comment: @Tats_innit I'm going to try for a while. But if i stuck in a point, i would like to ask it to you :)

Comment: @Timur Cooleos, perfect or let me know now I might give you the answer with demo, its getting late night at my part of the world now. :) Although I will be online for a bit, see you!

Comment: @Tats_innit Roget that. I'll absolutely let you know if i need help :)

Comment: @Timur I have a demo for you already here you go :) let me know if this fits your need I will set it as answer **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YfnjA/ B-) have a good one. *(Click on the row and drag it)*

Comment: @Tats_innit  yes its what i was trying to achieve. thanks for your help :)
but i still insist on developing my own. ;)

Comment: @Timur lol cooleos lemme know if you want me to set this as answer, it might save you some time, talk to you soon!

Comment: @Tats_innit dude, set it as answer.

Comment: @Timur :) Okies doing it now +1 to you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YfnjA/

Hope it helps.

When you will click on  and drag it will allow you to resize, rest you can play around and make it your way now :)

**code**

```
$(function() {
    var pressed;
    var start;
    var startX;
    var startWidth;
    var wrapper = $("div#wrapper");
    var container = $("table#container");

    $("table th").mousedown(function(e) {
        start = $(this);
        startX = e.pageX;
        startWidth = $(this).width();
        $(start).addClass("resizing");
        pressed = true;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(pressed) {
            var newWidth = startWidth + (e.pageX - startX);
            start.width(newWidth);
            wrapper.width(container.width() + 10);
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if(pressed) {
            $(start).removeClass("resizing");
            pressed = false;
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

some hints:

```
$(selector).width();

$(selector).mousedown(function(){});

$(selector).mouseup(function(){});
```